# Equation of the pulse function

Tags: functions

[image]

$$g(t)=\begin{cases}1&0\le x \le T_b\\0& x\not \in [0,T_b]\end{cases}$$

Express $x(t)$ in terms of $g(t)$.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @RobertLewis I edited the question. I think it's clearer now.

Comment: @ Sabyasachi:  Indeed it is.  Many thanks!

Comment: You have to do the convolution between g(t) and a set of three delayed and weighted dirac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a function $y=F(x)$ that is shifted a distance $d$ to the positive x axis can be represented as $y=F(x-d)$, $x(t)$ would be represented thus:

$x(t) = g(t-T_b)+3g(t-4T_b)+2g(t-6T_b)$

hope it helps